# Mongoose Query for value not in Array Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema as below.

```
const CampaignSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: true
        },

        enabled:{
            type: Boolean,
            required:true
        },
        expiring:{
            type: Date,
            required:true
        },
        likes: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        },
        image:{
            type: String
        }
    },
{
    timestamps: true // Saves createdAt and updatedAt as dates. createdAt will be our timestamp.
});
```

I am trying to run a query that returns a collection where a string value is not a item of the likes array.

How do I do this? I have tried the queries below :

Query 1

```
var email = [];
        email[0] = req.body.email;
            Campaign.find({"likes" : {"$nin": email}}, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'An error occurred on trying to pull the campaigns ' + err
                    });
                }

                res.status(200).json({success: true, result: result, message: 'Successfully pulled the Campaigns '});
            }).limit(20);
```

Query 2

```
Campaign.find({"likes" : { "$not": { "$all": [req.body.email] } }}, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'An error occurred on trying to pull the campaigns ' + err
                    });
                }

                res.status(200).json({success: true, result: result, message: 'Successfully pulled the Campaigns '});
            }).limit(20);
```

None of the above has worked.

Comment: Have you tried querying as `Campaign.find({"likes" : {"$ne": req.body.email }}, callback)`?

Comment: @chridam yes I have tried that

Comment: `Campaign.find({"likes" : {"$ne": req.body.email }}` is working perfectly for your use case. Perhaps you could share a small data set with us so we can try on that.